# pyspark generate row hash of specific columns and add it as a new column

Tags: pyspark, string-concatenation, sha256

I am working with spark 2.2.0 and pyspark2.

I have created a DataFrame `df` and now trying to add a new column `"rowhash"` that is the sha2 hash of specific columns in the DataFrame.

For example, say that `df` has the columns: `(column1, column2, ..., column10)`

I require `sha2((column2||column3||column4||...... column8), 256)` in a new column `"rowhash"`.

For now, I tried using below methods:

1) Used `hash()` function but since it gives an integer output it is of not much use

2) Tried using `sha2()` function but it is failing.

Say `columnarray` has array of columns I need.

```python
def concat(columnarray):
    concat_str = ''
    for val in columnarray:
        concat_str = concat_str + '||' + str(val) 
    concat_str = concat_str[2:] 
    return concat_str
```

and then

```python
df1 = df1.withColumn("row_sha2", sha2(concat(columnarray),256))
```

This is failing with "cannot resolve" error.

Thanks gaw for your answer. Since I have to hash only specific columns, I created a list of those column names (in hash_col) and changed your function as :

```python
 def sha_concat(row, columnarray):
   row_dict = row.asDict()      #transform row to a dict
   concat_str = '' 
   for v in columnarray: 
       concat_str = concat_str + '||' + str(row_dict.get(v)) 
   concat_str = concat_str[2:] 
   #preserve concatenated value for testing (this can be removed later)
   row_dict["sha_values"] = concat_str  
   row_dict["sha_hash"] = hashlib.sha256(concat_str).hexdigest()
   return Row(**row_dict)
```

Then passed as :

```python
    df1.rdd.map(lambda row: sha_concat(row,hash_col)).toDF().show(truncate=False)
```

It is now however failing with error:

```python
    UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ufffd' in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I can see value of \ufffd in one of the column so I am unsure if there is a way to handle this ?

Comment: Could you provide the exact error message. It would be interesting what can not be resolved. Did you correctly specify the `columnarray` variable?

Comment: Sure, Error message details: pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve '`COL2||COL3||COL4||COL5||COL6||COL7||COL8'` given input columns:

Comment: But finally you want to have the hash of all the concatenated values in each row?

Comment: I should point out that python has an easy way to join an array of strings with a separator. You can replace the entire body of your `concat` function with `return "||".join([str(val) for val in columnarray])`. (though as I showed in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52297410/5858851), there's a builtin spark function for this).

Comment: Hi gaw, I wanted to hash values of few specific columns in the row. I did not see response from pault earlier but am able to use the method provided. Thank you..

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use [`pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws) to concatenate your columns and [`pyspark.sql.functions.sha2()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.sha2) to get the SHA256 hash.

Using the data from @gaw:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import sha2, concat_ws
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1,"2",5,1),(3,"4",7,8)],
    ("col1","col2","col3","col4")
)
df.withColumn("row_sha2", sha2(concat_ws("||", *df.columns), 256)).show(truncate=False)
#+----+----+----+----+----------------------------------------------------------------+
#|col1|col2|col3|col4|row_sha2                                                        |
#+----+----+----+----+----------------------------------------------------------------+
#|1   |2   |5   |1   |1b0ae4beb8ce031cf585e9bb79df7d32c3b93c8c73c27d8f2c2ddc2de9c8edcd|
#|3   |4   |7   |8   |57f057bdc4178b69b1b6ab9d78eabee47133790cba8cf503ac1658fa7a496db1|
#+----+----+----+----+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

You can pass in either `0` or `256` as the second argument to `sha2()`, as per the docs:

> Returns the hex string result of SHA-2 family of hash functions (SHA-224, SHA-256, SHA-384, and SHA-512). The numBits indicates the desired bit length of the result, which must have a value of 224, 256, 384, 512, or 0 (which is equivalent to 256).

The function `concat_ws` takes in a separator, and a list of columns to join. I am passing in `||` as the separator and `df.columns` as the list of columns.

I am using all of the columns here, but you can specify whatever subset of columns you'd like- in your case that would be `columnarray`. (You need to use the `*` to unpack the list.)

Comment: thank you pault. I am able to use it by constructing columnarray which has to participate in hashing. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes in your case you would do: `df.withColumn("row_sha2", sha2(concat_ws("||", *columnarray), 256)).show(truncate=False)`

Comment: @pault - using spark 2.4 (pyspark) 

`columnarray = array([column_list])` - returns a column type.
I am not able to unpack with * operator with above. It gives the error - `TypeError: concat_ws() argument after * must be a sequence, not Column`.

But, it works just fine without the * operator when passing the column array with concat_ws. Not sure if it's an update with latest version.

Answer (score 3):

New in version 2.0 is the `hash` function.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import hash

(
    spark
    .createDataFrame([(1,'Abe'),(2,'Ben'),(3,'Cas')], ('id','name'))
    .withColumn('hashed_name', hash('name'))
).show()
```

wich results in:

```
+---+----+-----------+
| id|name|hashed_name|
+---+----+-----------+
|  1| Abe| 1567000248|
|  2| Ben| 1604243918|
|  3| Cas| -586163893|
+---+----+-----------+
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/functions.html#hash

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the hash for each value in the different columns of your dataset you can apply a self-designed function via `map`  to the rdd of your dataframe.

```python
import hashlib
test_df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1,"2",5,1),(3,"4",7,8),              
    ], ("col1","col2","col3","col4"))

def sha_concat(row):
    row_dict = row.asDict()                             #transform row to a dict
    columnarray = row_dict.keys()                       #get the column names
    concat_str = ''
    for v in row_dict.values():
        concat_str = concat_str + '||' + str(v)         #concatenate values
    concat_str = concat_str[2:] 
    row_dict["sha_values"] = concat_str                 #preserve concatenated value for testing (this can be removed later)
    row_dict["sha_hash"] = hashlib.sha256(concat_str).hexdigest() #calculate sha256
    return Row(**row_dict)

test_df.rdd.map(sha_concat).toDF().show(truncate=False)
```

The Results would look like:

```python
+----+----+----+----+----------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|sha_hash                                                        |sha_values|
+----+----+----+----+----------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|1   |2   |5   |1   |1b0ae4beb8ce031cf585e9bb79df7d32c3b93c8c73c27d8f2c2ddc2de9c8edcd|1||2||5||1|
|3   |4   |7   |8   |cb8f8c5d9fd7165cf3c0f019e0fb10fa0e8f147960c715b7f6a60e149d3923a5|8||4||7||3|
+----+----+----+----+----------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a copy and paste error (I didn't try to run your code), but the second row of your output looks wong. The order of the `sha_values` column is incorrect. Also why not just use `"||".join(some_array)` instead of looping over the values and concatenating manually? Regardless, there's no need to convert to `rdd` for this.

Comment: Yes thats true, the order got messed up by the conversion to dictionary i guess. I didn't use `join` because I wanted to reuse as much code from the original question as possible. Nevertheless, your solution seems to more straightforward

Answer (score 1):

if you want to control how the IDs should look like then we can use this code below.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

SRIDAbbrev = "SOD" # could be any abbreviation that identifys the table or object on the table name
max_ID = 00000000 # control how long you want your numbering to be, i chose 8.

if max_ID == None:
 max_ID = 0 # helps identify where you start numbering from.
dataframe_new = dataframe.orderBy(
    F.lit('name')
).withColumn(
    'hashed_name',
    F.concat(
        F.lit(SRIDAbbrev),
        F.lpad(
            (
                F.dense_rank().over(
                    Window.orderBy(name)
                )
                + F.lit(max_ID)
            ),
            8,
            "0"
        )
    )
)
```

which results to

```
+---+----+-----------+
| id|name|hashed_name|
+---+----+-----------+
|  1| Abe| SOD0000001|
|  2| Ben| SOD0000002|
|  3| Cas| SOD0000003|
|  3| Cas| SOD0000003|
+---+----+-----------+
```

Let me know if this helps :)