# Generate a UUID in a PySpark dataframe based on unique value of a field

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

Is there no way to currently generate a UUID in a PySpark dataframe based on unique value of a field?

I understand that Pandas can do something like what i want very easily, but if i want to achieve giving a unique UUID to each row of my pyspark dataframe based on a specific column attribute, how do I do that?

Say I have a pandas DataFrame like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['John Doe', 'Jane Smith', 'John Doe', 'Jane Smith','Jack Dawson','John Doe']})
df:
        Name
    0   John Doe
    1   Jane Smith
    2   John Doe
    3   Jane Smith
    4   Jack Dawson
    5   John Doe
```

And I want to add a column with uuids that are the same if the name is the same. For example, the DataFrame above should become:

```
df:
            Name        UUID
        0   John Doe    6d07cb5f-7faa-4893-9bad-d85d3c192f52
        1   Jane Smith  a709bd1a-5f98-4d29-81a8-09de6e675b56
        2   John Doe    6d07cb5f-7faa-4893-9bad-d85d3c192f52
        3   Jane Smith  a709bd1a-5f98-4d29-81a8-09de6e675b56
        4   Jack Dawson 6a495c95-dd68-4a7c-8109-43c2e32d5d42
        5   John Doe    6d07cb5f-7faa-4893-9bad-d85d3c192f52
```

```
import uuid

for name in df['Name'].unique():
    df.loc[df['Name'] == name, 'UUID'] = uuid.uuid4()
```

I was trying to search for it all over but could not find an example of doing this with PySpark.

Comment: i think i know what you want, but to make sure could u provide a reproducible sample data with desired output? it would help others understand your question too.

Comment: Something like the thing I just pasted above?

Comment: How about a [sha256 hash of your row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52292180/pyspark-generate-row-hash-of-specific-columns-and-add-it-as-a-new-column)

Answer (score 4):

What you actually want is applying a [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function). A hash function applied on the same value will always output the same result. An UUID on the other hand [is simply a 128 bits integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), so just apply a 128 bits hash function and interpret the result as UUID. For instance, [MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) is such a hash function.

```python
import hashlib
import uuid

def compute_uuid(name: str) -> uuid.UUID:
    digest = hashlib.md5(name.encode()).digest()
    return uuid.UUID(bytes=digest)

assert compute_uuid('alice') != compute_uuid('bob')
```

You can apply this new function to your dataframe

```python
df['UUID'] = [compute_uuid(name) for name in df['Name']]
```

Applied on your example dataframe I get

```
          Name                                  UUID
0     John Doe  4c2a904b-afba-0659-1225-113ad17b5cec
1   Jane Smith  71768b5e-2a0b-3697-eb3c-0c6d4ebbbaf8
2     John Doe  4c2a904b-afba-0659-1225-113ad17b5cec
3   Jane Smith  71768b5e-2a0b-3697-eb3c-0c6d4ebbbaf8
4  Jack Dawson  ba4f82d8-ef72-6e37-eb87-e5c3b0dce9e3
5     John Doe  4c2a904b-afba-0659-1225-113ad17b5cec
```

Comment: UUIDs are 128 bit integers, but not all 128 bit integers are valid UUIDs. Here is an example invalid uuid: 00000000-0000-6000-f000-000000000000 where the version is 6 (does not exist) and the variant is invalid (ends with 0 bit). [Learn more](https://www.uuidtools.com/decode)